# let ssh account only access specific directories

Tags: ssh

If you have an ssh account and a hacker can get his hands on your account then the hacker can almost do anything on your server. Is it possible to limit a ssh account to access only on some specific directories with some limited privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chroot was already mentioned. But now ssh has it built in for sftp transfers. You can disable shell access all together and use a configuration [similar to this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny).

Local root exploits are always a problem for distros there are only a few things you can easily do.

- Disable root logins and use sudo.
- Disable password authentication over ssh (use ssh keys with passphrases).
- Make home directories non browsable.
- Don't give out shell accounts if you can help it.

I take this a step further and I run ssh on a random high port to make it harder to find. Anymore specific then this and we'll need to know what distribution your using.

Comment: Nice description. I was busy at work when I posted, but wanted to point the OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

chroot is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of ideas. You can set up the accounts to use a restricted shell, e.g. `/bin/rbash`. Alternatively you can try is to add a `command=/bin/rbash` option to the authorized_keys file.

But all these are just idea. As usual, security is a process...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you move to using key pairs (with passphrases to add another factor) for SSH authentication.  My /var/log/auth.log is very quiet nowadays.